# How to do I group or join a query together to get the list of items I need

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a couple of tables:

```
Invoice
-----------------
ID        total     
1         500.00
2         100.00
3          10.00

Payment
---------------------------------------
ID    invoiceId     Amount   Method
1        1           400       CASH
2        2            60       CASH
3        2            40      CREDIT
```

I need a query that gets all invoices where at least one payment.method is CREDIT and the sum of all payments for that invoice is greater than the total of the invoice.

And I need it to be fast.

How can I do this?

Comment: I wrote a java program to do this but I need it as a single query and I have no idea how to get both the sum of the payments AND still be able to tell if there is at least one payment that is CREDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID InvoiceID,
        a.Total TotalInvoice, 
        b.TotalPayment
FROM    Invoice a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  InvoiceID, SUM(Amount) TotalPayment
            FROM    Payment
            GROUP   BY InvoiceID
            HAVING  SUM(Method = 'CREDIT') > 0
        ) b ON a.ID = b.InvoiceID AND
                a.Total < b.TotalPayment
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7af/3)

Comment: I think this gets me pretty darn close...testing now

Comment: maybe you mean the total payment made is greater than or equal total invoice example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7af/4

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
SELECT
  i.`id`,
  i.`total` AS `total_invoiced`,
  SUM(p.`amount`) AS `total_payments`,
  SUM(IF(p.`method`='credit', 1, 0)) AS `count_credit`
FROM `invoices` i
LEFT JOIN `payments` p ON (p.`invoice_id`=i.`id`)
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY i.`id`
HAVING (`total_payments` > i.`total`) AND (`count_credit` > 0)
```

I changed some table/field names. Sorry for the inconvenience.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7402d/1/0

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    select iagg.ID 
      from (
                select i.ID
                     , sum (p.amount)   tl_paid
                     , min (i.total)    tl
                  from invoice  i
                  join payment  p   on  ( p.invoiceID = i.ID )
              group by i.ID
           )  iagg
     where exists (
                select 1
                  from payment p2
                 where p2.invoiceId = iagg.ID
                   and p2.method    = 'CREDIT'
           )
       and iagg.tl_paid > iagg.tl
         ;
```

the minimum operator over the `total` attribute is mandated by the grouping operator, the minimum is actually taken from a set of identical values.